# mysql trigger in administrator tools

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using MySQL 5.1 Community Server. I have installed MySQL Administrator 1.2.12. The GUI Front-end is not showing anything to create and work with triggers. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the creation of triggers is more a thing of [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/) than it is a thing of MySQL Administrator.

Just a wild guess, though : the first one seems more suited for execution of SQL statements, such as statements used to create a trigger.

Actually, [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is probably even better for than : for instance, if I right click on a table in my schema and choose "edit", there is a "Triggers" tab -- but is apparently does no more than allow me to type SQL statements ; see the screenshot below :

[image]